# Using a variable as a operand in a expression - awk

Tags: awk, expression

I tried doing something like this in awk?

```
limit=10000  
ls -ltr | awk '$5 >= $limit { print $5 }'
```

But it doesn't seem to work, it prints all size less than the limit too.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use shell variables in awk script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-to-use-shell-variables-in-awk-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set variable in AWK's paramaters using -v option:

```
limit=10000
ls -ltr | awk -v mylimit=$limit '$5 >= mylimit {print $5}'
```

Comment: You should always quote variable, so `-v mylimit="$limit"` (It will work without in this simple case, but its better to always quote it)

Comment: Jotne, agree. My only excuse is that code just an example to show an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Change your awk command like below,

```
ls -ltr | awk -v limit=10000 '$5 >= limit { print $5 }'
```

you could declare an variable in awk itself using `-v` switch.

Comment: Thanks Avinash! But I'll accept Troublemaker-DV answer since he's got it first. Please don't mind. Cheers :)

Comment: your wish, but why you go for two lines instead of one?

Comment: Oh, hadn't considered that! I'll keep in mind next time!